# Applying hidden form value to identify which functions to run on a from handling page

Tags: php, forms, input, html-formhandler

I'm trying to carry a value from the form into my 'Formhandler' document but I can't get it to work. I tried adding a value (Register) to my html  tag but that did not work. I know that it's my "hidden" input field in the form that I need to change, I just can't resolve it myself. This maybe a simple fix but I can't see it and need fresh eyes on this problem. Thank you so much in advance.

```
<form id="signinform" action="<?php echo url_for('../Private/createuser.php');?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="Register" />
        <div class="formcontainer">
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formlabel">
            Email 
            </div>
            <div class="formfield">
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formlabel">
            First Name 
            </div>
            <div class="formfield">
            <input type="text" name="First_name" id="First_name" class="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formlabel">
            Surname
            </div>
            <div class="formfield">
            <input type="text" name="Surname" id="Surname" class="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="formlabel">
            Password 
            </div>
            <div class="formfield">
            <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" class="required" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <div class="longformlabel"><input type="submit" value="Register" class="formbutton" /></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Then the form handler code is;

```
    if($_POST['action']=='Register') {




        //VALIDATION------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $validated = new FormValidator();
        $validflag=true;

        if($validated->validateItem($_POST['Email'], 'email')) {
                $email=$validated->sanatizeItem($_POST['Email'], 'string');
        } else {
            $validflag=false;   
        }



    //END VALIDATION------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  


        if($validflag=true) {

                $usercheck=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `Users` 
                                    WHERE `Email`='{$_POST[$email]}'");

                                if(mysqli_num_rows($usercheck)>0) {
                                        $_SESSION['message']="Email address already in our database - please login or try registering a new account.";
                                        header("location: signup.php" . $processtext);  
                                    }


            $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);
            $salt=$bcrypt->getSalt();

            $hash = $bcrypt->hash($_POST['Password'],$salt);

            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Users ";
            $sql1 .= "(Email, Password) ";
            $sql1 .= "VALUES (";
            $sql1 .= "'" . $email . "',";
            $sql1 .= "'" . $hash . "',";
            $sql1 .= ")";

            $sql = "INSER INTO saltuser ";
            $sql .= "(Email, Saltstring) ";
            $sql .= "VALUES (";
            $sql .= "'" . $email . "',";
            $sql .= "'" . $salt . "'";
            $sql .= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($saltdb, $sql);
            $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql1);

            } else {
                // INSERT failed
                    echo mysqli_error($db);
                    db_disconnect($db);
                    exit;   
                }


    }
```

The error on the logs from the formhandler say that 'action' is undefined. Please help.

Comment: I don’t see anything obvious; could you add what print_r($_POST) reveals

Comment: I added 'print_r($_POST)' to my project and it didn't echo any text on on the handler page @TimMorton

Comment: Ok, that’s consistent with the undefined error. But it’s not just the hidden input. None of your data is getting to your script. Do you know how to use the console in your browser? You need to look at the network part and see if the data can s being posted. It probably is, but you need to confirm it.

Comment: If your browser is sending the post, then take a look at your php.ini settings for gpc_order.